How to seed local DB from remote supabase DB
I have a supabase database. I've been doing development locally by directly connecting to the remote DB. I want to move to a local dev environment for the DB so that my remote DB does not get impacted. I went through the supabase docs here and set it up. I ran migrations and the local database is up and running with all my tables. But there is no data. I see that I can put insert queries in the seed.sql file which runs after DB reset and applying migrations.
I would like to import the current data I have on my remote DB into my local dev database (either fully or partially) for local testing. Is there a way I can do this from the dashboard.
I thought I could download a copy of the backup and use that. But that includes some CREATE and ALTER statements. Not sure if that was a good idea.

If the downloaded copy is pg_dump output, you can add a --data-only to omit all DDL statements. If you're seeing create statements, it must've been a plaintext backup - if you run pg_dump yourself and switch to another format, the backup will be logically the same but smaller and faster to restore and you can also do pg_restore --data-only to skip the DDL statements even if pg_dump wasn't instructed to exclude them.
